# What are the differences between Knowledge Article Types and Knowledge object Record Types?

Tags: knowledge, articles

I am learning about knowledge articles and came across this two.

- In Setup->Quick Find, I can create a new article type, let say FAQ in Knowledge Article Types.
- However, if I go to Setup->Object Manager->Knowledge->Record Types, I can also create a FAQ type for Knowledge (I followed a trail in Salesforce trailhead about creating a new type called 'How To' for Knowledge Articles).

Are these two options the same or different and if so, in what ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowledge Articles are individual articles. For example, it might be how to fix a widget or run a report. This is similar to how you'd say that a record is an Account or a Contact. It is a specific instance of an article that contains information.

Knowledge Record Types are to define different *types* of articles, such as "How To" or "Troubleshooting."  You can think of Record Types as different categories of articles. They have different layouts and can contain different fields. Each Knowledge Article is a certain Record Type. This is similar to how you'd say that a record is a Business Account or a Household Account--the same base object, but having a different layout and different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you click "Enable Lightning Knowledge" in Knowledge Settings, article types will not be available any more. All further configuration should be done by Record Types.